# JAXB Validation

Tags: validation, jaxb

I converted XML into JAXB element using xjc and performed marshalling operation.
But,some of the fields in xml are not validated against xsd.

For eg: I have given one of the field as integer , but its accepting string and does not throw validation error.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB (JSR-222) is designed to by default carry on if part of the document does not correspond directly to the mapping.  You can specify an instance of `ValidationEventHandler` to be notified of any conversion issues.  For more validation you can set an instance of `Schema` on the `Unmarshaller` (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html).

Comment: Whether marshaller doesnt  perform validation? In our method,we are passing the argument as JAXBElement to handle both XML and JSON.To perform unmarshalling,we need to pass argument as string.Please,suggest me some solution.